# spring boot application.properties are not loading

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, application.properties

I've two projects called A and B, B depends on A. We generate library (A.jar) and place in a local repository so that B can look into local repo for dependency resolution.

I've class called C.java in project A which reads properties from project B property files.

This is working perfectly fine but If I try to add any new property to `xyz.properites`, its not getting loaded and keep on getting below error while starting the server for project B

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'c': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.x.y.z.C.app; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'app' in string value "${app}"
```

Project Structure

```
Project A
        --- src
        --- main
            --- java
                --- C.java (It reads xyz.properties)
            --- resources
                --- source.properties
        

Project B
        --- src
        --- main
            --- java
            --- resources
                    --- common
                        --- xyz.properties
                    --- dev
                        --- application.properties
                    --- test
                        --- application.properties
                    --- live
                        --- application.properties
```

I'm not able to understand what is the issue as other properties except newly added property (app) in `xyz.properties` are getting loaded fine using `@Value("${property}")`

Comment: Do you rebuild everythign after adding that property? You can check the resulting .jar  to see what is inside the xyz.properties file.

Comment: Yes. I found what is the issue. We've abstract class which reads different property files like xyz.properties (abc.prop, def.prop). I've to define every new property in all the property files or I've to define it in source.properties under A and override it only in xyz.properties instead of defining it in all other property files under B

Comment: What a weird architecture!